# Obtener valor de una variable creada dentro de una función ejecutada en segundo plano

Tags: linux, bash, script

de antemano gracias por la ayuda prestada.

Este es mi codigo:

```
#!/bin/bash

#funcion que se ejecurara en segundo plano
function init(){

    file="archivo.txt"
    #creando variable
    var1=$(./script.sh $file)

}

init &


w=$(jobs -l)
t=""

#bucle que espera la terminacion del subproceso
until [[ $w = $t ]]; do
    echo "esperando... que termine el proceso init"
    sleep 5
    jobs -l
    w=$(jobs -l)
    echo $w
done

#Salida del valor de la variable creada en el subproceso
echo "$var1"
```

No logro capturar el valor de la variable "$var1" creada en la función que se ejecuta en segundo plano.. alguna idea?.

**eh intentado**

```
export var1=$(./script.sh $file)
```

y tampoco funciona

Comment: y si exporta la variable `export var1 = valorVariable`

Comment: Ya lo eh intentado y no funciona, parece que el proceso padre no puede capturar los datos definidos en los procesos hijos

Comment: @isaac Si te refieres a incluir esa linea dentro de la función no funcionará. export hace accesibles las variables para los sub-procesos. No al reves.

Comment: Haz pensado usar un archivo socket o un LIFO? No creo que sea posible con lograr eso con variables.

Comment: @loki No había escuchado esas opciones, si tuvieses un ejemplo te lo agradecería mucho

Answer (score 1):

Este es un ejemplo de un `FIFO` ó named pipe. Basicamente es un archivo del cual se puede leer y escribir. Con este puedes comunicar tus dos procesos. Sólo modifica tu código para que use redirección en lugar de variables.

```
mkfifo var1
function init(){
    file="archivo.txt"
    #creando variable
    ./script.sh $file
    rc=$?
    echo $rc > var1
}
...
#Salida del valor de la variable creada en el subproceso

cat < var1
```

Comment: La salida del comando `./script.sh $file` es texto plano, y al parecer cuando utilizo `./script.sh $file > var1` se me queda atrapado en el bucle esperando a que termine la función que nunca termina. Eh utilizado guardar la salida en un documento de texto y poder llamar ese archivo desde el proceso padre pero no creo que sea el mejor camino

Comment: Modifique la respuesta para que tome en cuenta el código de retorno.

Comment: esto funciono para mi `./script.sh $file > var1` y cuando se ejecute la funcion en segundo plano `init &` invoco al comando `salida=$(cat < var1)` de esta manera se ejecuta el comando que esta en la funcion y guardo el resultado, cuando termine el proceso saldrá del bucle. Muchas gracias por la info

Answer (score 1):

Trata de usar *named pipes* para que los procesos se comuniquen entre ellos.

```
#!/bin/bash

fifo=/tmp/fifo1
[[ -e $fifo ]] && rm $fifo  # Si existe, entonces lo borramos
mkfifo $fifo  # Luego lo creamos

init() {

    file="./archivo.txt"
    ./script.sh $file > $fifo
}

init &

var1="$(< $fifo)"  #  Aquí accedemos a su contenido y se lo asignamos
                   #+ a la variable var1
echo "===== var1 es: ====="
echo "$var1"
```

Y cuya salida sería, claro, dependiendo de lo que haga el programa `script.sh`

```
===== var1 es: =====
El contenido es:
hola
```

Comment: Mucas gracias, es una buena solución... creo que es la única solución que hay ante este caso jaja Gracias nuevamente

Comment: Ahora tengo un problema, Cuando se ejecuta la funcion 
`init &` y se crea la variable `var1="$(< $fifo)"` el proceso se  queda esperando a que la función termine para poder avanzar. La idea es que la función quede en segundo plano y el script pueda seguir avanzando

Comment: Entonces tal vez no necesites una variable, sino un archivo que se vaya llenando en background con el resultado de `script.sh` y justo cuando lo necesites, abres ese archivo, ese archivo ya sea normal o sea un *named pipe*. Y claro, luego lo borras.

Comment: Gracias.. eso fue lo que pensé.. quería evitar la creación de archivos pero creo que me tocara crearlos.